# Java Spring - ManyToMany Call Error - Object references an unsaved transient instance

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a problem with a repository call to an object's attribute, which is part of a `Many-To-Many` relationship.

I am trying to get all the lecturers assigned to a specific course (getting all the courses for a specific lecturer works very well). But when I am calling the method from the repository below I get the 
error:

`org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: app.model.Course`

The `CascadeType` is set for both parts of the relationship.

I have the following configuration:

**Lecturer**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "LECTURERS")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class Lecturer extends AbstractUser {

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = Course.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @JoinTable(name = "COURSE_OWNERSHIPS",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "lecturer_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "course_id")})
    @JsonSerialize(using = CustomCourseListSerializer.class)
    private List<Course> courses = new ArrayList<>();

    ...
}
```

**Course**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "COURSES")
@JsonIdentityInfo(
        generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
        property = "id")
public class Course implements Item, Serializable {

    ...

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "courses", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = Lecturer.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    @JsonSerialize(using = CustomLecturerListSerializer.class)
    private List<Lecturer> lecturers;

    ...
}
```

**Lecturer Repository**

```
public interface LecturerRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Lecturer, Long> {

    ...

    Page<Lecturer> findAllByCourses(Course course, Pageable pageable);

}
```

**Edited**

**Course Service Method**

```
@Override
    public Page<Lecturer> getLecturers(Course course, int page) {
        return lecturers.findAllByCourses(course, new PageRequest(page, 10));
    }
```

**Edit 2**

**Full course service method**

```
  @Override
    public Page<LecturerDto> getLecturers(CourseDto course, int page) {
        Type listType = new TypeToken<Page<LecturerDto>>() {}.getType();
        return modelMapper.map(lecturers.findAllByCourses(modelMapper.map(course, Course.class), new PageRequest(page, 10)), listType);
    }
```

I've tried a few things but I can't make it work. Do you have any idea why I encounter this? I would like to do this because I want the lecturers of a course paginated.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you post the code calling `findAllByCourses`? Also, I'd strongly advise against using `CascadeType.ALL` (which implies `CascadeType.REMOVE`) in many-to-many relationships

Comment: You're right about the CASCADE.ALL. Thank you. About the code for that method I can't post it because it's generated by Spring JPA. It uses their query method syntax and builds the query based on the method. I've used a similar aproach for the CoursesRepository. And the method works just fine, so I think there is a problem with the relationship or some of the annotations.

Comment: I meant the code that's using it, not the implementation

Comment: My bad, I've misread it. I've edited the post with the calling code. It just a service method that returns a specific page with the lecturers.

Comment: Strange. Does `getLecturers` get called from another service method, within a transaction? It would seem that upon the implicit flush before query execution, there is a managed `Lecturer` entity referencing an unsaved `Course`.

Comment: In this method there is a ModelMapper conversion to the Dto version of the objects. I didn't included it at first because I thought the code is not as readable (i've edited the post and included it). Besides this the getLecturers method is called in the controller where it simply returns the page if it's not empty. The course sent as parameter is queried before this method is called and sent as parameter.

Comment: This may be a long shot, but I'd try changing `findAllByCourses` to `findAllByCoursesId` with the course id as a parameter

Comment: I just tried this and it works :). Thank you. Can you explain why this works? It looks after the id directly rather than the full object? And maybe in the full object case because of the modelMapper it won't associate them corectly? Anyway, I'm glad it works. You can answer the post so I can select is the correct answer. This way it will be more visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `findAllByCourses` to `findAllByCoursesId` with the course id as a parameter.

`findAllByCourses` would be perfectly fine if called from within a transaction, and with the `course` argument being a managed entity. In your code, however, it is called with an entity that is not managed by JPA (as it is assembled by `modelMapper.map(course, Course.class)` and never merged into the persistence context). Apparently, JPA doesn't like that.

The solution is simply not to use finder methods with detached entities as query parameters.

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot.